# How can I solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'+\frac{xy}{x^2-4}=\frac{e^x}{x-3}$$

Since it is linear, 
$$y(x^2-4)^{1/2}=\int\frac{(x^2-4)^{1/2}e^x}{x-3}dx$$ 
How can I continue?

Comment: Wolfram says, it doesn't have a closed form, so most likely it doesn't.

Comment: I highly doubt that integral has an elementary solution.  I'd just divide both sides by $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ and call it done.